# Putting a link from html to a localhost

Tags: php, html, hyperlink, localhost

I would like to put a link in my HTML site to access my database. However, my database is localhost/abc.php (located inside xampp/htdocs).

I was wondering how to add the link because it it a localhost document. I could not do it with the `<a href="localhost/abc.php">` or the `c:///xampp/htdocs/abc.php`.

Comment: is your file abc.php located in the htdocs folder? Then your link would be localhost/abc.php  as you have. Or as noted by others have you included http protocol in front?)  But if your doc isn't in that location you will have to tell us where it is. when you just type localhost in your browser does it come to the default page that is set up when you install Apache as part of xampp?

Comment: Have you tried adding `http://` before localhost?

Comment: It worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

`<a href="localhost/abc.php">` is a *relative URL*.

It points to a directory named `localhost` in the directory of the current URL.

You need an absolute URL: `http://localhost/...`

Answer (score 3):

use

```
<a href="http://localhost/abc.php">to my db</a>
```

that will work.

In detail:

"localhost" is the hostname of the url your are pointing to.

It needs to be prefixed with the protocol you are using. In this case http://

Happy new year.